# Looping cells on an excel file using python3

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to this page. I've managed to find myself in a little bit of an issue. Using python I'm looking for a way to loop through the different cells of an excel column using pandas and dataframes. The code I'm using is:

```
variable = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column'])
for cell in variable:
    print(cell)
```

And this only prints the first cell.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas what you've got is a pandas dataframe. By looping over it as you are, pandas lets  you loop over the columns. If you want the rows, try the methods in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but here is a way to remove duplicate entries of the same text within a column in a dataframe.

```
df = df[df.column_name.apply(lambda x: x != 'Player')]
```

This loops through the whole column in the dataframe and ofcourse you can update the code to the action you want after the colon.

Comment: What I am trying to do is by using a 'for loop' cycling through the different cells on a determined column. So I can after that apply it to an SOAP request so that I can automate every time a new request is introduced. For example: having in one column the client ID and the second the amount they are trying to charge it. Edit: Sorry if I'm not being clear, I'm from Argentina and my english it's a bit rusty.